# How do I write text from one file to another after modification in C#?

Tags: c#

If I have a .txt file with

> Hello, @@. @@ how are you doing?

how could I copy this from the .txt file and then paste it into another one but replace the "@@"'s with the string.

Comment: [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have the code that gets the string to replace the "@@"s with. I just don't know like how to do it/where to go next. I did look at using StreamWriter although I'm not sure how to use it to do what I would like.

Comment: When you get access to internet beyond SO please consider searching before asking here - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+read+write+text+file (or similar searches on other search engines) would give you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by this

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\test\a.txt");
string s = text.Replace("@@", "new text");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\test\b.txt", s);
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.